# Is it possible to include a PackageReference inside of a Target?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I'd like to do something like this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PowerShellModule Include="PackageManagement" Version="1.4.6" />
    <PowerShellModule Include="PowerShellGet" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PowerShellModule Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive" Version="1.2.4.0" />
    <PowerShellModule Include="ThreadJob" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="AddPowerShellModuleReferences" BeforeTargets="Restore">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="%(PowerShellModule.Identity)" Version="%(PowerShellModule.Version)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

So that I can reuse the Names & Versions of my `PowerShellModule`'s in other targets in the file.

Is there a way to put a `PackageReference` inside of a `Target`? Also, can I be sure that the same instance of `PowerShellModule` is being used for the reference to `Identity` and `Version` to the name and version will be correct?